# How to save local image to Django's model?

Tags: django

I've got some images in static dir which is located in 'apps/app_name'.
I want to save this images while model instance creation.

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.logo:
        self.logo = ...
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I tried this:

```
        file = FileIO(os.path.join(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0], 'app_name/image.png'))
```

but i've got an error:

```
 The joined path (/home/.../image.png) is located outside of the base path component (/home/.../media)
```

Here is my settings.py :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_collected')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

Comment: Are you trying to save the image to DB like MSQL?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge to PostgreSQL